# Error: your app has not been accepted into Android Auto

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have update ui and some functionalities in my app but after uploading on play store I got an email that my app is not accepted into AndroidAuto while my app is only for Android Mobile Devices.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Android Auto declaration from the manifest/merged manifest and the automotive_app_desc.xml file. Otherwise, the app will automatically opt-in for Android Auto review.

Android Auto declaration -- >"android: name="com.google.android.gms.car.application""

1.Review the checklist to prepare your APK.
2.Sign in to your Play Console.
3.Select the app with the policy violation.
4.On the left menu, select Release management > App releases.
5.Next to the release type you want to create, select Manage.
6.To create a new release, select Create release.
7.Follow the on-screen instructions to upload the modified, policy compliant APK **across all tracks**, and deactivate the non-compliant APK(s).
To deactivate a non-compliant APK, please upload a compliant APK to the same track.
Be sure to increment the APK version number and **set the release to 100% rollout**, in order to successfully override and deactivate the non-compliant APK.
Submit your app